# How to dynamically import Django settings variables?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I want to import Django settings dynamically.

something like this:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.get('TIMEOUT_CONFIG', 10)
```

but this thing doesn't work.

I also tried this

```
settings.__dict__.get('TIMEOUT_CONFIG')
```

but this thing also won't work before I call it like this

```
settings.TIMEOUT_CONFIG
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
from django.conf import settings

def get_variable(key, default):
    return getattr(settings, key, default)


TIMEOUT_CONFIG = get_variable('TIMEOUT_CONFIG', 10)
```